# How do i declare a 2D Array in Kotlin. Without initialise the array with value's

Tags: kotlin

Anybody know a short and easy way ?

I found a function that work's good but still got value's.

`var tilemap = Array<IntArray>(sizeX,{IntArray(sizeY,{-1})})`

Comment: What do you want the default value to be? This is not C++, you can’t have undefined values in an array

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to initialise there, you have three options:

1. Using `lazy` [[docs]](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties)
2. Using `lateinit` [[docs]](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables), but that means, you will just place initialisation somewhere else
3. Using ArrayList (it contains pointers to it's elements, maybe it will be enough of *not initialisation*)